# Condition for value function to be strictly concave

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the optimization problem
$$
c(p) = \min_x \sum_{i=1}^n x_ip_i
$$
subject to $f(x)\geq 1$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^n_+\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is increasing and concave. I know that $c$ is concave (see [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/22354/prove-all-cost-functions-are-concave-in-input-prices-and-demand-for-inputs-is-do) for a proof). My question is: are there conditions on $f$ such that $c$ is strictly concave? Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that since $f$ is increasing, $p_i \geq 0$ for all $i$; otherwise we do not have the solution for problem. Then at the optimal solution $x(p)$, we must have $f(x(p))=1$. Using this remark, one sufficient condition for $c(p)$ is strictly concave is that $f$ is strictly concave.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why this implies that $f$ strictly concave is a sufficient condition. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: If $f$ is strictly concave then solution $x(p)$ is unique. Then you can reproduce the proof you mentioned with the strict inequality.